# Syntax error in function in c

Tags: c, syntax

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h> 
#define N 15
int random_generator(int );

int arr_move(int);
int main()
{
    int j, a, x,i,sayac;
    int arr[N] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };



    printf("Enter your start station(0-15): ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("My player is started from station-%d\n", a);
    a = a - 1;


    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        arr_move(arr[N]);


        while (arr[j] = 0)
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", arr[i]);
        printf("\n");
        sayac += sayac;
    }
    while (x = 0)
        printf("and visited all station after  move");
    return 0;
}


int random_generator(int random)
{

    srand(time(NULL));
    random=rand() % 3 ;
    return 0;
}
int arr_move(int sarr[] , int b)
{
    int num;

    random_generator(5);
    if (num = 0)
    {
        sarr[b - 1] += 1;
        b = b - 1;
    }
    if (num = 1)
    {
        sarr[b] += 1;
        b = b;
    }
    else
    {
        sarr[b + 1] += 1;
        b = b + 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

missing ';' before 'type' line 39 where is my syntax error?im using 89 visual studio 2010.
how can i fix it?
I couldn' find where  is the error 
So thanks for helping
.........................................................

Comment: And which line is 39??

Comment: If the code's indention wouldn't be such a mess you'd propably spotted the mistake immediately.

Comment: @alk Although indentation won't make the second parameter in `arr_move` definition match the declaration and call :-) (that will give a linker error though.)

Comment: Indent your code properly. You have a } missing somewhere. Also, `if (x = 0)` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Get a better IDE to sort out the indentation. Trouble with braces - that is why you are caught with this problem

Comment: `random_generator(5);` always returning `0` and you are not assigning it to any variable.

Comment: Also, you've written `sayac += sayac;` without initializing `sayac;`

Comment: `while (x == 0)` (when corrected) may loop never or always. I think you want neither.

Comment: `arr_move` triggers Undefined Behavior when its parameter `b` is 0 and that awful `rand` code returns 0. (Checking) uh ... which it always *will*.

Comment: ... I guess you believe changing a function *parameter* changes the original value as well. Not so in C. Review your code with this new insight.

Answer (score 4):

```
   for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
   {
        arr_move(arr[N]);
```

This loop in `main` function has no closing `}`.

Moreover, the function declaration `int arr_move(int);` does not match the `arr_move` definition (different parameters type).

Answer (score 0):

```
 while (arr[j] = 0)
```

is not what you want i guess

it should be

```
 while (arr[j] == 0)
```

Similarly

`while (x = 0)` should be `while(x == 0)`

`if (num = 0)` should be `if (num == 0)`

Along with this fix

```
   for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        arr_move(arr[N]);
    }
```

Comment: There is at least one `if (...)` with the same mistake too.

Comment: also `while (x = 0)` and `if (num = 0)`

Comment: Would that really produce a syntax error though?

Comment: @juanchopanza: apart from the error, I get 4 warnings for these. OP should enable all warning checks.

Comment: @Jongware Sure, the thing is a bag of bugs.

Comment: why down vote on this I agree lot of bugs are thre atleast these might fix few of them

Comment: The downvotes most likely arose because the 1st versions of your answer did not address the question, the syntax error.

Answer (score -1):

2 Things

1. Missing Bracket of main }
2. The arr_move define below is different from the above declaration.

The correct code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h> 
#define N 15
int random_generator(int );

int arr_move(int[],int);
int main()
{
    int j, a, x,i,sayac;
    int arr[N] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };



    printf("Enter your start station(0-15): ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("My player is started from station-%d\n", a);
    a = a - 1;


    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        arr_move(arr,N);


        while (arr[j] = 0)
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", arr[i]);
        printf("\n");
        sayac += sayac;
    }
    while (x = 0)
        printf("and visited all station after  move");
    return 0;
}
}


int random_generator(int random)
{

    srand(time(NULL));
    random=rand() % 3 ;
    return 0;
}
int arr_move(int sarr[] , int b)
{
    int num;

    random_generator(5);
    if (num = 0)
    {
        sarr[b - 1] += 1;
        b = b - 1;
    }
    if (num = 1)
    {
        sarr[b] += 1;
        b = b;
    }
    else
    {
        sarr[b + 1] += 1;
        b = b + 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please DO NOT quote/adopt the messy indention! Please!

Comment: i just tried to remove the errors.